# Room Generic @RawQuery

Tags: android, generics, android-room

I create generic BaseDao and wanted to add generic @RawQuery fn, but when build project get error.

```
interface BaseDao<T> {
     /*...*/

     @RawQuery
     fun findOneBy(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): LiveData<T?>
}
```

I know room not support generic @Query but I don't know support generic @RawQuery. SO my question: **It is possible to create generic @RawQuery?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. Room is just a code generator. You can't generate code from classes that you don't know on compile time.

You will need to annotate on your interface implementations instead.